# Three.js MaskPass with Glitch Pass

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

Hey I am trying to combine the MaskPass example with the GlitchPass example from threejs.org/examples but for some reason adding a renderPass breaks the MaskPass. Can anyone explain why this is?

code:
                `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xe0e0e0 );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.autoClear = false;
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

```
            //

            var clearPass = new THREE.ClearPass();

            var clearMaskPass = new THREE.ClearMaskPass();

            var maskPass1 = new THREE.MaskPass( scene1, camera );
            var maskPass2 = new THREE.MaskPass( scene2, camera );

            texture1 = new THREE.Texture(videoImage);
            texture2 = new THREE.Texture(videoImage);
            texture1.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture1.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture2.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            texture2.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

            var texturePass1 = new THREE.TexturePass( texture1 );
            var texturePass2 = new THREE.TexturePass( texture2 );

            var outputPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
            outputPass.renderToScreen = true;

            var parameters = {
                minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
                format: THREE.RGBFormat,
                stencilBuffer: true
            };

            var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, parameters );

            composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer, renderTarget, 1 );

            composer.addPass( clearPass );
            composer.addPass( maskPass1 );
            composer.addPass( texturePass1 );
            composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
            composer.addPass( maskPass2 );
            composer.addPass( texturePass2 );
            composer.addPass( clearMaskPass );
            composer.addPass( outputPass );
            // composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene1, camera ) );
            // glitchPass = new THREE.GlitchPass();
            // glitchPass.renderToScreen = false;
            // composer.addPass( glitchPass );`
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this??

Comment: I am using the code straight from threejs.org and trying to combine the two examples. Here is the relevant code